# Json4s - extract to correct trait implementation based on kind property

Tags: scala, json4s

I have a trait that has many implementations. When in json format you can distinguish easly between them by `kind` property. Is there a some simple way to have json4s pick correct implementation based on that property?
I would prefer to avoid writing huge custom serializer to handle each case individually.

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
class ExampleTest extends WordSpecLike with Matchers {

  implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats + new CarSerializer

  val teslaJson =
    """
      |{
      | "name": "Tesla",
      | "kind": "electric",
      | "batteryCapacity": 250.0
      |}
    """.stripMargin
  val bmwJson =
    """
      |{
      | "name": "BMW",
      | "kind": "petrol",
      | "tankCapacity": 70.0
      |}
    """.stripMargin

  val tesla = ElectricCar(
    "Tesla", "electric", 250.0
  )

  val bmw = PetrolCar(
    "BMW", "petrol", 70.0
  )

  "JSON4s" should {
    "extract electric car" in {
      parse(teslaJson).extract[ElectricCar] should be(tesla)
    }
    "extract petrol car" in {
      parse(bmwJson).extract[PetrolCar] should be(bmw)
    }

    "extract electric car with CarSerializer" in {
      parse(teslaJson).extract[Car] should be(teslaJson)
    }
  }

}

class CarSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Car](_ => ( {
  case car: JObject =>
    car \ "kind" match {
      case JString(v) if v == "electric" => car.extract[ElectricCar]
      case JString(v) if v == "petrol" => car.extract[PetrolCar]
    }
}, {
  case car: Car => Extraction.decompose(car)
}))

sealed trait Car {
  def name: String

  def kind: String
}

case class ElectricCar(
  name: String,
  kind: String,
  batteryCapacity: Double
) extends Car

case class PetrolCar(
  name: String,
  kind: String,
  tankCapacity: Double
) extends Car
```

Unfortunately it does not work as `extract` and `decompose` functions require implicit formats to be present but the serializer itself is meant to be part of the formats.

Comment: is there a reason you are creating a serializer instead of using polymorphic lists (https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serializing-polymorphic-lists)?

Comment: thats sounds like it may be we I need. I will try it in coming days.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this mate?

Comment: I am not actively working on that project anymore, but just had a quick look at the code there and seems like I did manage to get it working with the TypeHints from  Assaf link.